# Collection of clopen sets form a base for a countable completely regular space

Tags: general-topology

I have $X$ as a countable, Tychonoff space, and I want to show that the collection of clopen subset of $X$ form a base for the topology on $X$.

Can I first just define a base $\mathscr{B}$ of X, let $x\in X$ and $E \subset X$ is closed such that $x\notin E$. So $x\in X-E$, which is open.

I also noticed that the interval $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Can I define a function $f: X\to [0,1]$, then f is onto. Do I need to show that $f$ continuous next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ is countable, there are no surjective functions $f : X \to [0,1]$.  In fact, this is of central importance to the proof (at least as I see it).  Perhaps looking at this hint/question will direct you in the right path.

**Hint:** If $f : X \to [0,1]$ is continuous and $r \in [0,1] \setminus f[X]$, what sort of set is $f^{-1} [\,[0,r]\,]$?  $f^{-1} [\,[0,r)\,]$?  How do these two sets compare?

Also, note that it suffices to show the following:

> Given any $x \in X$ and any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is a clopen set $V \subseteq U$ which contains $x$.

Comment: so we can just assume that $f$ is continuous? $f^-1[0,r]$ is closed since f is cont. What two sets that I should compare, aren't they the same thing?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Well, in my hint $f$ is by assumption continuous.  And, yes, those two sets should be the same.  The outline of the proof should be as follows: Given $x \in X$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ "find" (using complete regularity) a continuous function $f : X \to [0,1]$ so that for an appropriate $r$ we have $0 \in f^{-1} [\,[0,r]\,] \subseteq U$.

Comment: @Arthur : I think you meant $x \in f^{-1}[[0,r]] \subseteq U$. P.s. : It is totally non-standard to use brackets instead of parenthesis to denote maps of functions, i.e. the standard would be $f^{-1}(A)$ instead of $f^{-1}[A]$, or $f(A)$ instead of $f[A]$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Yes, your first observation is correct.  As for the second, in the fields that I work in it is _quite_ common to use $f^{-1} [ \cdot ]$ to denote inverse images of sets.  For the simple reason that it is not uncommon for elements of a set to also be subsets of the set in question (especially when working with ordinals).  So to avoid possible confusion differing notation is used.  Of course, if you insist, perhaps you should inform [Brian M. Scott](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/373610/8348) that he also uses incorrect notation.

Comment: You mean that you wish to distinguish $f^{-1}(a)$ when $f$ is injective and $f^{-1}$ is the inverse map, and $f^{-1}(A)$ when $A$ is a subset of the codomain of $f$ (so that we would write $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}[A]$ or $f(a)$ and $f[A]$)? (Maybe that your field of study uses non-standard notation for the right reasons, but I don't know you so I can't guess that when I read your answer. :P)

Comment: Hi, Arthur. Your answer is wonderful.

Comment: @Patrick: You may not have seen the notation before, but there is nothing non-standard about using $f^{-1}[A]$ for $\{f^{-1}(a):a\in A\}$ and $f^{-1}(A)$ for the unique $B\in\operatorname{dom}\,f$ such that $f(B)=A$ when $A$ is actually an element of the range of $f$.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: How do I show that there is a clopen set $V\subset U$ which contains x? And I still can't get it yet, do I need to work with the close set E?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: This is the heart of the problem, and is what my hint is attempting to direct you towards.  Suppose that $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$.  Can you think of a way to use complete regularity to get a continuous function $f : X \to [0,1]$ such that $x \in f^{-1} [\,[0,r)\,] \subseteq U$ for all $0 < r \leq 1$?

Comment: So you meant to say $f^-1[(o,r)]$ al along, and this set is clopen in X, right?

Comment: @ArthurFischer:   
And by completely regularity, I have $f(x)\in f(U)=0$ and $f(X−U)=1$, how would that help me though?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Recall that a topological space $X$ is _completely normal_ if given any $x\in X$ and any closed $F\subseteq X$ which does not contain $x$ there is a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(z)=1$ for all $z\in F$.  What would be really nice is if given $x \in X$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, for an appropriately chosen continuous function $f$ there was an $r \in [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1} [\,[0,r)\,]$ where a clopen set containing $x$ and a subset of $U$.  We know that $f^{-1}[\,[0,r)\,]$ is always open (by continuity), why would it be also closed?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: because f(x)=0? I don't really get it. Can we just fet that $f^-1[0,r)$ is clopen since $[0,r)$ is clopen? But my question is how to show that x is in $f^-1[0,r)$ and $f^-1[0,r)$ is a subset of U

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: $[0,r)$ is not a clopen subset of $[0,1]$; it is an open subset of $[0,1]$  (since $[0,r) = (-1,r) \cap [0,1]$ and $(-1,r)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$).  (In fact, the only clopen subsets of $[0,1]$ are $\varnothing$ and $[0,1]$ itself.)  If $f(x) = 0$, then clearly $x \in f^{-1} [\,[0,r)],] = \{ z \in X : 0 \leq f(z) < r \}$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: And is it correct to say that $f^-1[0,r)$ is a subset of U since $f(X-U)=1$?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Yes!

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Phew!!